# Retaining text formatting in XML

Tags: xml

I have some data that I would like to store in an XML file. (It doesn't have to be XML, but XML is a nice, open format.)

The data consists of nodes and child nodes (no limit on depth), and every single node can have some text.

My data might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nodes>
  <node title="root">
    <node title="child1">
      Here is some text for child1.
    </node>
    <node title="child2">
      Here is some text for child2.
    </node>
    <node title="child3">
      Here is some text for child3.
    </node>
    Here is some text for root.
  </node>
</nodes>
```

But the problem with this approach is that I'm ending up with a lot of whitespace that wasn't in the original text. For example, the text for my root node has 10 newlines and a bunch of tabs (or spaces) in order to format the child nodes nicely.

What's a good way to use XML to store data this way, but retaining the original text exactly, without adding any additional whitespace characters?

Note: I assume I could just have all the data without newlines or indents like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nodes>
  <node title="root"><node title="child1">Here is some text for child1.
</node><node title="child2">Here is some text for child2.
</node><node title="child3">Here is some text for child3.
</node>Here is some text for root.
</node>
</nodes>
```

I guess that eliminates any new whitespace. But is that the best way? It's about as ugly as it could be. And some XML viewers might format the tags by adding whitespace.

Comment: Maybe this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: XML is *not* a format. XML is a document markup language for describing its contents. How it gets displayed has nothing to do with XML. If you want to change how it's displayed, set up your editor to do that.

Comment: @Rob: I don't believe anyone said XML was a *format*. But there are standard ways to format XML markup, and I have an editor that will do it automatically if I ask it to. I'm just trying to figure out how to safely store text in an XML document and ensure I don't end up with any additional characters. Also, it would be nice if the document was easy to read, but perhaps that's asking too much.

Comment: Your first sentence: XML is a nice, open format. Yes, your editor can do that. No, XML cannot.

Comment: @Rob: Well, okay. Wikipedia defines XML as *"a markup language that defines a set of rules for encoding documents in a **format** that is both human-readable and machine-readable."* That's how I meant it. But, fine, it's not a format.

Comment: Is the downvoter going to say why this is a bad question? Or don't they have the grapes?

Comment: Read the spec, not Wikipedia. Even then, that is about the format for how XML is interpreted, not displayed.

Comment: @Rob: Fine, it's not a format, Wikipedia is wrong, and you are right. Not sure what that gets us.

Comment: It gets us back to the point that XML has nothing to do with display of its contents. https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-intro

Comment: @Rob: Okay, maybe you can show where I said that then.

Comment: You are saying you want to change how XML is displayed cause you're not happy with new lines, tabs, etc. XML has nothing to do with that other than for purposes of separating elements within it. XML is not like HTML in that regard.

Comment: I wonder if I should actually put all that as an answer.

Comment: @Rob: No, I'm not saying I want to change how XML is displayed. We seem to be going back over a question that no one asked. I said I have a viewer that can do that, and that it would be nice if it was easier to read, but not that I want to change the layout of the markup.

Comment: @Rob: You're right to encourage people to think of XML as not being about presentation, but even with that admonition in mind, there's still room for Jonathan's question to have merit.  [See below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626080/290085)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's separately consider unmixed and mixed content:

### Unmixed Content

When no text can be mixed between your elements, simply manage whitespace within elements as you wish, and allow XML serializers and editors to manage the whitespace between elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nodes>
  <node title="root">
    <node title="child1">Here is some text for child1.</node>
    <node title="child2">Here is some text for child2.</node>
    <node title="child3">Here is some text for child3.</node>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

This works fine for both data-oriented and document-oriented XML.  (OOXML is an example of document-oriented XML that doesn't need mixed content.)

### Mixed Content

When text can be mixed between your elements, decide how to manage whitespace depending upon the semantics of your data.  For example, if your data is like HTML, multiple consecutive space mean nothing different than a single space, so allowing XML serializers and editors to manage the whitespace is fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nodes>
  <node title="root">
    <node title="child1">Here is some text for child1. </node>
    <node title="child2">Here is some text for child2. </node>
    <node title="child3">Here is some text for child3. </node>
    Here is some text for root.
  </node>
</nodes>
```

### `xml:space`

If some portion of your XML associates importance to embedded whitespace, you can signify this by adding a special `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to the containing element:

> [**2.10 White Space Handling**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space)
>
> In editing XML documents, it is often convenient to use "white space"
>   (spaces, tabs, and blank lines) to set apart the markup for greater
>   readability. Such white space is typically not intended for inclusion
>   in the delivered version of the document. On the other hand,
>   "significant" white space that should be preserved in the delivered
>   version is common, for example in poetry and source code.
>
> An XML processor must always pass all characters in a document that
>   are not markup through to the application. A validating XML processor
>   must also inform the application which of these characters constitute
>   white space appearing in element content.
>
> A special attribute named `xml:space` may be attached to an element to
>   signal an intention that in that element, white space should be
>   preserved by applications. In valid documents, this attribute, like
>   any other, must be declared if it is used. When declared, it must be
>   given as an enumerated type whose values are one or both of
>   `"default"` and `"preserve"`.

You should take care to use `xml:space="preserve"` conservatively, however.  Placing it on the root element of a complex XML format such as OOXML is likely to make [consumers of your data justifiably unhappy](http://www.jenitennison.com/2007/07/13/things-that-make-me-scream-xmlspacepreserve-in-wordml.html).

Comment: I also read that support for xml:space was spotty. But this is certainly a complete answer. Thanks.