# Can someone please help me explain to others about non-significant whitespace in XML?

Tags: xml, formatting

**Problem:** People think that XML should look in a special way when viewed in a text editor and think that completely proper XML that validates against a schema is somehow "incorrect" because they look at it as text and it does not look like what they saw somewhere else.

I.e. that to a parser:

```
<foo><bar>4711</bar></foo>
```

is the same as

```
<foo>
  <bar>4711</bar>
</foo>
```

In addition, what they *do* see will be different if they use Notepad, or Notepad+, or a web browser, or a proper XML editor like Editix.

Is there a handy resource that I can point these people to, instead of wasting a lot of time explaining?

Comment: This is a plaform about programming issues.  This question is here off-topic. Please visit superuser.com

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig: No, it's very much on-topic as it asks about an XML definitional issue (not how to get an application to behave, which would indeed be off-topic).  It's been answered before, though; see [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625085/retaining-text-formatting-in-xml).

Comment: @kjhughes  he asks about " handy resource that I can point these people to"  and this is not answered in the "duplicate"  or do you ment that the duplicate is the handy resouce :-/

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig: That's just a way of asking for an authoritative answer.  The essence of OP's question pertains to the significance of whitespace in XML, which is both on-topic here and answered by the duplicate link.

Comment: The protocol for StackOverflow is that you should ask direct questions: "How do I calculate the square root of 42?" is a valid question, "Can you recommend a book telling me how to calculate square roots?" is not. (Sadly, don't blame me, I didn't make the rules).

Comment: @kjhughes Agreed. I was asking for an answer. Whether the answer is here or linked is irrelevant :) My question was essentialy regarding non-significant whitespace. The suggested answer does explain some of it and I find the reply by Rob particularily useful.